# What am I doing wrong in this call to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this in html

```html
<div class="btn-group tags_select">
<a href='' id='<?php echo "plus".$base['id']?>' class='btn btn-flat btn-primary btn-sm'><i class='fa fa-plus'></i><?php if(in_array("manageAsset",$perms)) {  echo $base['id']; }?></a>
<a href='' id='<?php echo "minus".$asset['id']?>' class='btn btn-flat btn-success btn-sm disabled'><i class='fa fa-minus'></i><?php if(in_array("manageAsset",$perms)) {  echo $asset['id']; }?></a>
</div>
```

this is the javascript:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var array = [];
var len;


    $('.tags_select a').click(function() {

        var value = $(this).text();
        var input = $('#asset_array');

        if($('plus'+value).click()){
            console.log("clicked plus");
            document.getElementById('plus'+value).classList.add('disabled') ;
            document.getElementById('minus'+value).classList.remove('disabled');
            if(!array.includes(value)){
                array.push(value);
                console.log(array);
                input.val(array.toString());
            }
        }

        else if($('minus'+value).click()){
            console.log("clicked minus");
            document.getElementById('minus'+value).classList.add('disabled') ;
            document.getElementById('plus'+value).classList.remove('disabled');
            if(array.includes(value)){
                array.pop(value);
                console.log(array);
                input.val(array.toString());
            }
        }




        return false;
    });
  
  </script>
```

There are 2 buttons, minus is turned off while the plus is on. When i click on plus the minus should be on and plus off ( as it is), but the output for minus gives me only log for ('clicked plus'). Does this mean i need separate id calls in document?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for your conditional won't work here. You're not going to be able to check whether the link has been clicked by checking `if($('plus'+value).click()){` because your conditional is effectively checking the returned value of `$('plus'+value).click()` and JQuery's `click()` method returns nothing/null.

What you would be better off checking is the id of the target of the `click` event. So firstly you would have to include the event as an argument being passed to the click handler like so:

`$('.tags_select a').click(function(evt) {`

The argument there has information you can access about the event's target, which in this case is the anchor `<a>` tag that has been clicked.

So what you could check in this case would be the `evt.target.id` which would contain either "plus" or "minus":

```
if(evt.target.id.includes("plus")) {
  //proceed with logic for "plus" link having been clicked
} else if(evt.target.id.includes("minus")){
  //proceed with logic for "minus" link having been clicked
}
```

Mind you, the `includes()` method I'm using here is vanilla javascript and JQuery may have a call that does the same thing. No harm in mixing the two though.

You can find more information about `event.target` here if you like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Comment: Oh, I didn't know if I could mix them safely. Thank you for the in-depth explanation, it help's a lot.

Comment: One weird thing happens using your code, in debugger it sometimes wont register user click...

Comment: ... The issue is caused by fa fa-minus & fa fa-plus... Thanks again for great solution.

Comment: I'm very glad that my solution has helped. For what it's worth though, I've got this code working as expected in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/flyingace/jy0ub24c/15/ and the `fa fa-minus` and `fa fa-plus` aren't causing any problems. Maybe have a look at that and see if it helps at all.

Comment: It registers the click, but the color doesn't change nor does the function execute... ill add picture. Only happens if I click directly at the number or the plus/minus if a bit from them it does exactly what it should.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$('minus'+value).click()` you are triggering a click event, not evaluating whether or not that element was clicked.

Comment: Yes, that is it. Thank you :)